# What's the meaning of `()` in git command SYNOPSIS?

Tags: git, syntax, posix

In the [synopsis](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) of `git reset`:

> 'git reset' (--patch | -p) [<tree-ish>] [--] [<paths>...]

I have an issue with the markers' meaning.

I know `[]` stands for options, `<>` stands for replacement. But, what's the meaning of `()`? 
If there's no `|`, are the parentheses still needed?

I didn't find relative clues in POSIX [Utility Conventions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap12.html).

Comment: The implication is that to get this version of the command, you *must* use one of those two options, `--patch` or `-p`.

Comment: Have a look at `git stash`, which also has a version using parentheses.

Comment: Thanks, @torek. That sounds reasonable. Does git expect the readers to infer that meaning? I didn't find any reference for using parentheses in the command synopsis.

Comment: See [user5241578's much more complete answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32085970/1256452).  It's not all that common since this is syntactically a "required option", which is a little self-contradictory, but I will note that [Python's `argparse` has support for it, and uses parentheses in its usage syntax](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html#mutual-exclusion).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is covered in git's [CodingGuidelines](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/CodingGuidelines), found on their Github. It gives contributors a style guide while also describing how help options should be written. Other sources like POSIX or BSD should not be taken as authoritative, especially since they don't always conform to POSIX<sup>1</sup>. The following excerpt is near the bottom of the file:

```
Placeholders are spelled in lowercase and enclosed in angle brackets:
   <file>
   --sort=<key>
   --abbrev[=<n>]

Optional parts are enclosed in square brackets:
   [<extra>]
   (Zero or one <extra>.)

   --exec-path[=<path>]
   (Option with an optional argument.  Note that the "=" is inside the
   brackets.)

   [<patch>...]
   (Zero or more of <patch>.  Note that the dots are inside, not
   outside the brackets.)

Multiple alternatives are indicated with vertical bars:
   [-q | --quiet]
   [--utf8 | --no-utf8]

Parentheses are used for grouping:
   [(<rev> | <range>)...]
   (Any number of either <rev> or <range>.  Parens are needed to make
   it clear that "..." pertains to both <rev> and <range>.)

   [(-p <parent>)...]
   (Any number of option -p, each with one <parent> argument.)

   git remote set-head <name> (-a | -d | <branch>)
   (One and only one of "-a", "-d" or "<branch>" _must_ (no square
   brackets) be provided.)

And a somewhat more contrived example:
   --diff-filter=[(A|C|D|M|R|T|U|X|B)...[*]]
   Here "=" is outside the brackets, because "--diff-filter=" is a
   valid usage.  "*" has its own pair of brackets, because it can
   (optionally) be specified only when one or more of the letters is
   also provided.
```

<sup>1</sup>: The following excerpt is at the top of the file:

> Like other projects, we also have some guidelines to keep to the code.
>   For Git in general, a few rough rules are:
>
> - Most importantly, we never say "It's in POSIX; we'll happily    ignore your needs should your system not conform to it."    We live in
>     the real world.
> - However, we often say "Let's stay away from that construct,    it's not even in POSIX".
> - In spite of the above two rules, we sometimes say "Although    this is not in POSIX, it (is so convenient | makes the code    much more
>     readable | has other good characteristics) and    practically all the
>     platforms we care about support it, so    let's use it".
>
>   Again, we live in the real world, and it is sometimes a
>     judgement call, the decision based more on real world    constraints
>     people face than what the paper standard says.

Answer (score 0):

From MANUAL PAGES(5), BSD File Formats Manual, section "MANUAL PAGE SYNTAX":

> In some cases, you may even see entire groups of arguments wrapped with brackets and separated by a vertical separator. This is one way of showing that a command has more than one valid syntax. In other manual pages, this is expressed by having multiple lines in the synopsis, each of which begins with the command name. The separated format is more common (and more readable), but is not always possible for commands with particularly complex syntax. Finally, the most important notational convention is the use of the ellipsis (...). This indicates that additional arguments may be added at this point.